# OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_1 always appear..,why?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

```
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
import tensorflow as tf
import os

def picread(fileList):
    """
    读取狗图片并转换成张量
    :param fileList: 文件路径 + 名字的列表
    :return: 每张图片的张量
    """

    # 1. 构造文件队列
    file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filelist)
    print(file_queue)
    # 2. 构造阅读器去读取图片内容（默认是按一张图片）
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    key,value = reader.read(file_queue)

    # 3. 对读取的图片数据进行解码
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value)

    # 4. 处理图片的大小（统一大小）
    image_resize = tf.image.resize_images(image,[200,200])

    image_resize.set_shape([200,200,3])  # 批处理要求形状必须固定

    # 4. 进行批处理
    image_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image_resize],min_after_dequeue=10,batch_size=20,num_threads=1,capacity=40)

    return image_batch


if __name__ == "__main__":

    file_names = os.listdir("/Users/yuxiao/Desktop/test1/")
    filelist = [os.path.join("/Users/yuxiao/Desktop/test1/",file) for file in file_names]
    print(len(filelist))
    image_batch = picread(filelist)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
        # 定义一个线程协调器
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

        # 开启读文件的线程
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess,coord=coord)
        for i in range(200):
            print("第",i,"次")
            sess.run([image_batch])
        # 回收子线程
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 15, current size 10)

The exception always appeared,and it appeared randomly,sometimes 180th,sometimes 170th. There are 5890+ small jpg image in my folder. it not reached the end of my filelist.I just want to know why? The problem has spend my whole 4 hour,and  no solution.Who can help me ?Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the output to see if you see any shape mismatch error.

The sample code you've shared worked for me when I used a dataset that has all 3 channel images. Later I added, a GrayScale image and observed the error that you are seeing.

Comment: Very Thanks!! I checked my flolder,and found 3 hidden files!! when i added the condition of` "filelist = [os.path.join("/Users/yuxiao/Desktop/test1/",file) for file in file_names if file.endswith(".jpg")]"`,it goes well.i got the error information just on my google cloud machine,and it didn't appear in my own mbp computer.Thanks again~!